# Append an input's value in included form..PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have several landing pages and the only difference in them is a hidden input's (referred_by_text) value. I would like to just make one form and include it in all the landing pages....**how would I go about setting the value for the input on each landing page for that value?**

In the landing page this:

```
<?php include("includes/lp_form.php");?>
```

In the included form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referred_by_text" value="" />
```

I would like to set the value for "referred_by_text" in each landing page...not sure where to start, any help is much appreciated. Would it be best to do it as an variable or possibly in JS?

Comment: The answer is in the question itself. Where the referred_by_text value comes from?

Comment: What are you trying to set `referred_by_text` to exactly?

Comment: what do you need in this hidden field ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to set - it's in an include that will be deployed on about 10 different landing pages. I want to set it on each individual landing page

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design set it to what?

Comment: @wanovak - it will be set to a value that corresponds to where the lead is coming from. They are names of either publications or ad networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter "includes/lp_form.php" to expect a variable for the "referred_by_text" value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referred_by_text" value="<?php echo $referred_by_text; ?>" />
```

Then set the value in your page-specific script before including "includes/lp_form.php"

```
$referred_by_text = 't2w'; // Or other dynamic value, as needed

include "includes/lp_form.php";
```

Comment: Hold on, I get echoing the value, it just tells it to get the value from the varialble $refered_by_text...but not real clear on the "HTTP_REFERRER" i need to be able to set it to something like "t2w or tl etc" an arbitrary code we use to track where it came from... would I just do it as such "$referred_by_text = 't2w'" ?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: Yes, you are exactly right. If there is a specific value that you need to insert, you use it instead of the HTTP_REFERER. I will update the answer to reflect your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to echo out the value you want. You could try something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referred_by_text" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>" />
```

That will appear blank if there was no referer.

Comment: I need to be able to change the value, not clear on HTTP_REFERER

Answer (score 1):

In the include that contains the form with the hidden text field, you could set the value based on the page that is visited. For example, in the include file you can create an array of your landing pages and then

```
$landingPages = array('landingpage1' => 'referred_by_text_value', 'landingpage2' => 'referred_by_text_value', 'landingpage3' => 'referred_by_text_value');
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

if(array_key_exists($page, $landingPages)) {
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="referred_by_text" value="'.$landingPages[$page].'" />';
}
```

This will put the value you want based on the array key into the hidden field.

Comment: So it's checking the page name, then pulling the corresponding value from the array for that page name? The page name might not match the value used, IE the page name could be "Page Foo" but the value could be "PF". Unfortunately these values are "set in stone" I cannot change them.

Comment: Well, it checks the name of the file (like pagename.php or something) so you'd put the file names that are set in stone into the array as keys and make each key's value the value you want set in the hidden field.